# String Split and Create New Columns

Tags: regex, string, split

I have a column `soil.test` that contains information in this format:

```
P = High, K = Medium, and pH = 6.1.
```

I want to split this string and create three new columns.
A column called `P` that contains just the word that appears after the `P =`, a column called `K` that contains just the word that appears after the `K =`, and a column called `pH` that contains just the values after `ph =`

Comment: In what language? This sounds like a database/SQL question, which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
^\s*P\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*,\s*K\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*,\s*and\s+pH\s*=\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

`$1` is `P`, `$2` is `K` and `$3` is `pH`

Answer (score 0):

This is the short regex you're looking for:

```
(?<== )\S+
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/12).

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<== )` asserts that what precedes is an `=` and a space
- `\S+` matches any non-whitespace characters